# Rails creating through via association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Student Model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
end
```

Course Model:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end
```

How can I create courses via students so that I get [Course id: 1, student_id: 1]. I've tried the following way but it gives me student_id nil.

Course Controller:

```
@course = Student.find(params[:id])
@course = @course.new(params[:course])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several minor problems with you solution, but if I understood well what you are trying to do, which is basically create Course object associated with a Student inside some action at courses_controller, all you need to do is add those lines ate the courses_controller action:

Courses_controller:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def new
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    @course = Course.new student_id: @student.id
  end 

  def create
    @course = Course.new(params[:course])
    @course.save
  end

  ... 

end
```

And inside your view that you are calling the new_course_path you should pass the :student_id value, like this example:

```
new_course_path(student_id: @student.id)
```